# How to check if the string in one column is included in another column but 2 columns contain different rows?

Tags: r, string, match, detect

I have 2 tables and each of them contains different number of rows and columns.

Illustration:

**Table A:**

| PID | Region |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | East |
| 123457 | South |
| 123458 | West |
| 123459 | East |
| 123450 | North |

**Table B:**

| Product | Colour | Customer ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tech | Yellow | 987654 |
| Furniture | Red | PID123456 |
| Fruit | Blue | 0012345700 |
| Food | Red | PID112345 |
| Clothes | Green | 123458 |
| Books | Black | XXX101010 |
| Shoes | Blue | 123459MD |

I want to check for every PID, if they can be found in any row of customer ID (could be exact match - the exact PID is appeared in customer ID; or the PID is included as part of the string in Customer ID). If yes then show 'mapped' in the new column of Table A, if no then show 'notmapped'.

**Ideal output:**

| PID | Region | New column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | East | mapped |
| 123457 | South | mapped |
| 123458 | West | mapped |
| 123459 | East | mapped |
| 123450 | North | notmapped |

I've tried `grepl` but it gives error as 2 tables contain different number of rows. `str_detect` also doesn't seem to work.

Hence would like to pick your brain and seek your advice.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sapply()` with `grepl()`:

```
A$mapped = sapply(A$PID, \(s) any(grepl(s, B$`Customer ID`)))
```

The above returns a boolean in `A$mapped`.  To get the labels above, you could wrap the call to `any()` in an `ifelse()`, like this:

```
A$mapped = sapply(A$PID, \(s) ifelse(any(grepl(s, B$`Customer ID`)), "mapped", "notmapped"))
```

Output:

```
      PID Region    mapped
1: 123456   East    mapped
2: 123457  South    mapped
3: 123458   West    mapped
4: 123459   East    mapped
5: 123450  North notmapped
```

You can also do this by row. If, for example, `A` and `B` are data.tables, then you can do this:

```
A[, mapped:=fifelse(any(grepl(PID, B$`Customer ID`)), "mapped", "notmapped"), PID]
```

(or, using dplyr approach):

```
A %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(mapped = if_else(any(grepl(PID, B$`Customer ID`)), "mapped", "notmapped"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.
In my real code, this is one of the outcome in my 'mutate = case_when (...' condition.

Comment: I tried all your 3 solutions. 
The sapply gives me Error: unexpected input in : sapply (A$PID,\" 
The 2nd solution gives me Error of could not find function: ":="
The dplyr works only if I put rowwise() %>% , I researched on the usage for rowwise but not sure if it means this would capture every row of result (ie row by row) in both tables for matching purpose despite different number of rows in the 2 tables.
Thanks very much again!

Comment: The first error is probably due to using an old version of R. You can replace the shortcut `\(s)` with `function(s)`

Comment: The second error is that you probably did not see my qualifier re `data.table`. Try ` library(data.table)` and make sure that your frames are converted to data.table using `setDT(A)` and `setDT(B)`

Comment: Not sure I understand your third issue. The dplyr code works on each row of `A`